# dll runtime error(C/C++/GCC/MSVC)

Tags: c++, dll, gcc

After two days fighting, I make the dll(compiled in GCC/G++) link correctly in MSVC, but while debuging, I got the runtime error, is say that:

> Runtime Error!
>   Program: my_exe.exe
>   This application has required the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I have test something in that way: compiled a dll in mingw/gcc, link and debug in MSVC, it works correctly ,but while I implement it in my large project, I got the runtime error.
And I tested the dll in mingw/GCC, it works correctly, it says that the runtime error does not come from programming error,it comes from the dll imcompatible between different platform. Does anyone can hele me? Thanks, forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I compiled my dll in MSVC, and link it correctly in MSVC. While debug, I really got some memory error, and steped into the dll-codes. But while the dll compiled in mingw, it would not step into the actual dll code, and just throw a 'Runtime Error'.

Yet, after update my dll-code, I have not test whether the mingw-compiled dll works well in MSVC, but I am shure that, if you want to debug your dll which compiled in mingw in MSVC, it's not a smart choice.

Thanks for all of your concerns!